# Failed to resolve dependencies in the react native project

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

My react native project is trying to resolve dependencies as locally. But it can't find anything and make these errors:

> Could not find javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>
> file:/C:/Users/oop/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras
> /m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
>
> file:/C:/Users/oop/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras
> /m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
>
> file:/C:/Users/oop/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/google
> /m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
>
> file:/C:/Users/oop/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/google
> /m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
>
> file:/C:/Users/oop/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/android
> /m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
>
> file:/C:/Users/oop/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/android
> /m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
>
> file:/C:/Users/oop/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject
> /1/javax.inject-1.pom
>
> file:/C:/Users/oop/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject
> /1/javax.inject-1.jar
>
> file:/D:/react/Barbari/node_modules/react-native/android/javax/inject
> /javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
>
> file:/D:/react/Barbari/node_modules/react-native/android/javax/inject
> /javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
>
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject
> /1/javax.inject-1.pom
>
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject
> /1/javax.inject-1.jar
>
> Required by:
>
> project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.3

I think the gradle searches first the local maven directory and it can't find the files.
I'd like to know is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Windows--**  Open android studio >>  **Preferences** > **File** > **Settings**
**Mac--** Android Studio > Preferences)

then "**Build, Execution, Deployment**" > **Build Tools** > **Gradle** and disable the "Offline work" checkbox

apply and ok